# How to parse JSON with JavaScript from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this code:

```javascript
GameManager.prototype.initGame = function () {
    var api  = 'my_url';
    $.ajax({
        url : api,
        type : 'POST',
        data: "",
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
};
```

I see in the Firebug console the JSON:

```javascript
[{"data":{"score":500,"token":"2896c5380bf3e3e29467258c7fe885fe"}}]
```

But the `alert(data)` shows me `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`.

Answer (score 1):

The object will already have been parsed when using:

```
dataType : 'json'
```

This is what the doc says:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript objec

You can read more about the dataType parameter here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried ?

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);

alert(json["score"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON.Stringify().

[JSON.Stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is for strings ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log)). I think you are doing everything ok, you just need to get certain properties from your object, eg. `data.score` if you want to output them using `console.log`, because I assume you will be working with data ir JSON format, and not in `stringified` version.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**JSON.stringify()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method to display the data of `JSON` object in `alert`. It will convert the `JSON` Object into `JSON` String.

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
 "data": {
  "score": 500,
  "token": "2896c5380bf3e3e29467258c7fe885fe"
 }
}];

alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```